# HighCharts Drag points saving with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, json, graph, highcharts

I would like to save my model, by clicking on the button SAVE, after dragging a few points, in HIGHCHARTS.

This is my fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/nicolas1000/efv0vvbp/

Unfortunatly, $scope.test doesn't show any change after Dragging a point and clicking save !

THank you if you have any idea !

code :

```
look at fiddle
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i've just resolved it finally, Still dont know how to specify a resolved stuff on this web site, a button is missing thank you. I ve updated the fiddle

Comment: Your original post i a question, so the natural way to resolve it was for this post (the answer) to actually specify the steps you took to resolve the issue so that others in the same situation can get help from your answer, and give you votes for its validity.